# dplyr: max and min between a row and a specific value

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm trying to create the code that results in the max value between a given row and a specific value, but I don't know how to do it. I've seen some suggestions here, but they are only applicable to several values ​​of the row

Here is a simple example, of my expected result. I want the max value between the "Start" and 19:00:00 (I´m using hms)

```
Type | Start    | max_value_between
<chr>| <hms>    |   <hms>
 A   | 19:30:00 |  19:30:00
 B   | 18:45:00 |  19:00:00
```

thanks in advance

Comment: if you can subtract time, I would look for the min and max of Start - 19:00:00

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

data <- tribble(
  ~Type, ~Start, 
  "A", "19:30:00",
  "B", "18:45:00"
) %>% 
  mutate(Start = hms::as_hms(Start))

data %>% 
  mutate(
    max_value = if_else(Start > as_hms("19:00:00"), Start, as_hms("19:00:00"))
  )


# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Type  Start  max_value
#   <chr> <time> <time>   
# 1 A     19:30  19:30    
# 2 B     18:45  19:00
```

Comment: Hi Zaw! tks a lot. Could you tell if i can use the same assumption to extract only dates from a DataTime in format POSICXct, example "2020-12-13 19:39:34" >> result: 2020-12-13?

Comment: You can use a base R function `as.Date()` to extract the date form a POSIXct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmax`:

```
mydata$max_value_between <- pmax(mydata$Start, '19:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(max_value_between = max(Start, "19:00:00")) %>%
   ungroup
```